# Correct way to use k-means cluster- python-scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am working with Python, pandas and scikit-learn. I have a dataset where I have the number of sales per shop. I have the date and the hour of this sales and I want to forecast the sales for the next month.

I have tried different approaches trying to forecast per individual shops, using all the data and different things but with a high error using ARIMA models.

Then I realised that may be if I train a k-means cluster I can automatically group the shops that are similar between them and then train an ARIMA model to predict per each groups that my cluster has assing.

The way I have done that is why I am posting this question, because I don't know if I have though it in a correct way.

I have grouped per shop the sales and then I have calculated the average and the standard deviation per each shop. I have trained a k-means clustering with 4 clusters, to group the shops that has similar average and standard deviation.

Do you think that is correct this procedure of grouping each shop calculate the the average and standard deviation per each one and group them in 4 clusters?. The reason for 4 clusters is for  group the shops that has similar average and similar standard deviation like divide the data in quartiles.

Comment: How does the feature space of your data look like? As in which features do you include for the clustering?

Comment: - How does the feature space of your data look like?
 I don't understand the question.

- As in which features do you include for the clustering?

I am including average and standard deviation per each shop

Comment: You could do that but then you assume that cluster together with these attributes are similar. It really depends on how the data looks like. In the end you are dealing with timeseries analysis and you are now trying to cluster according to summary statistics of these time series. Could work. Since you only have two dimensions you can plot your data and see if the clustering makes sense. For more versatile clustering check out hierachical clustering or EM-clustering.